# XSLT - Select all nodes if node attribute is value

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to select all of the records that have a value attribute with a value of more than threshold. The data that I have in my `$dataset` is shown below:

```
 <component name="Information Technology" value="5712"/>
 <component name="NADCO" value="5033"/>
 <component name="Electronic Security" value="2104"/>
 <component name="SATT" value="1608"/>
 <component name="E-Business Office" value="291"/>
 <component name="Systems Development" value="158"/>
 <component name="Test" value="694"/>
```

I also have a `$threshold` that has a value of `4000`. The code I'm using to get the components that have a value higher than 4000 is:

```
<xsl:variable name="records" select="$dataset/self::node()[@value &gt; $threshold]"/>
```

So I expect `records` to be a list of the components `Information Technology` and `NADCO`, but the variable is empty. Where did I go wrong?

*ps note that I do not have a root node*

**EDIT**
The code that makes the dataset is the following

```
<xsl:variable name="dataset" select="$components/component" />
```

And `$components` is

```
<components>
     <component name="Information Technology" value="5712"/>
     <component name="NADCO" value="5033"/>
     <component name="Electronic Security" value="2104"/>
     <component name="SATT" value="1608"/>
     <component name="E-Business Office" value="291"/>
     <component name="Systems Development" value="158"/>
     <component name="Test" value="694"/>
</components>
```

Comment: Does `$dataset/node()[@value &gt; $threshold]` return any data?

Comment: @TimC No it does not. I tried `$dataset/self::node()/@name` and that returns `Information Technology`  so I don't understand why I cant filter on the value

Comment: For the `$components` I'm selecting a `components` node

Comment: And does `$threshold` definitely contain 4000? What happens when you try `$dataset/self::node()[@value &gt; 4000]`?

Comment: when I set 4000 as a literal it works. huuray:) I looked around a bit more and $threshold is a param that was set higher than 4000 somewhere else which resulted in no component values passing the filter... Thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it the following way:

1. `dataset` variable contains `components/component`
   (collection of `component` tags, as you did).
2. The *XPath* expression is `$dataset[@value &gt; $threshold]`, i.e.:

   - `$dataset` - the variable (container of records).
   - `[@value &gt; $threshold]` - a predicate.

As you see, there is even no need for `self::node()`.

So the whole example template matching `main` (root) tag
(containig `components`) looks like below:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="dataset" select="components/component"/>
    <xsl:variable name="threshold" select="4000"/>
    <xsl:variable name="records" select="$dataset[@value &gt; $threshold]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$records"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It works even in version 1.0 / Xalan. For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWsz

Comment: Thanks for noting that the `self::node()` isn't necessary. Had it already working but this kind of small improvements are welcome:)